# Get ID or value of a checkbox onclick of that checkbox in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, getelementbyid

I'm working on a script for my company that, upon clicking a checkbox:

- Fires function `OptionSelected()`
- Gets `ID` of that checkbox
- Performs a bitwise operation based on that `ID`

Or, preferably:

- Fires function `OptionSelected()`
- Fetches the integer assigned to that checkbox (`<input="checkbox" value="2"`, get `2`)
- Performs bitwise operation with that `value`.

To debug, I am having my code return to me an alert with the value inside. I've yet to write the bitwise operations portion.

Here is my js code:

```
function OptionsSelected(e)
{
    alert(e.target.id);
}
```

And the example checkbox it references:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkgrp" onclick="return OptionsSelected(e)" value="2" id="eXAMPLE"><LABEL id="LeXAMPLE"></LABEL>
```

When I click the box in runtime, I get this javascript error message:

[image]

Does anyone have a fix for this? I suppose it's rather simple, so in addition to supplying your fix, would you explain *why* your fix works?

Bonus points if your solution saves me time by directly pulling the bitwise `value` in place of the actual `ID`.

Note: I can't employ the `GetElementByID` method because I'll be *fetching* the `ID` or `value`, not using it to perform an action.

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: replace **e** with **this**. So it will be: `onclick="return OptionsSelected(this)"` and `alert(e.target.id)` with `alert(e.id)`. That should work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call the script using the `onclick` attribute, you are calling the function yourself.  So in this case, you're passing a variable called `e` which you've never defined.

Instead, you could pass a reference to the checkbox that you clicked:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkgrp" onclick="return OptionsSelected(this)" value="2" id="eXAMPLE"><LABEL id="LeXAMPLE"></LABEL>
```

And in `OptionsSelected` you would do this:

```
function OptionsSelected(me)
{
    alert(me.id);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! With a good explanation. Thank you, this solved my issue.

As an aside, by changing `alert(me.id)` to `alert(me.value`), I am able to directly pass the bitwise value that I need. The best of both worlds have been achieved!

Comment: Also, if you're not already doing so, you should add a `for` attribute to your label, so it is clickable (e.g., `<label for="eXAMPLE">...</label>`

Answer (score 2):

Variable `e` is not defined when you are calling your function `OptionsSelected`.
To resolve that you can either go with Tom's solution.

or

Looking at your attached error message, i guess that you tested your code on IE.
Just for your reference, 'target' property is not supported by IE,they use `srcElement`.
so you could do something like this :

In html,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkgrp" onclick="return OptionsSelected(window.event)" value="2" id="eXAMPLE"><LABEL id="LeXAMPLE"></LABEL>
```

In javascript,

```
function OptionsSelected(e)
{
   alert((e.target || e.srcElement).value);
}
```

so that it will work on all the browsers.